# Compile a kernel module (error stage 2, MODPOST 0)

Tags: linux, makefile, module, kernel

I'm trying to compile a sample kernel module (test.c) on my Arch linux just typing *make* in the directory with source and Makefile.

It creates empty folder *.tmp_versions* and empty files *Module.symvers* and *modules.order*, but no *.ko*

I also tried to compile it under virtual machine with Ubuntu, but I have absolutely the same output. Samples were from the Internet (2 ones).

What I should do else to compile it?

Makefile:

```
obj−m += test.o
default:
 $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
clean:
 $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

But it shows me:

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.18.14-arch1-1-ARCH/build SUBDIRS=/home/hime/Documents/module modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/lib/modules/4.18.14-arch1-1-ARCH/build'
Building modules, stage 2.
MODPOST 0 modules
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/lib/modules/4.18.14-arch1-1-ARCH/build'
```

or (verbose):

```
make    -C  "/lib/modules/4.18.14-arch1-1-ARCH/build"   SUBDIRS="/home/hime/Documents/module"   modules V=1
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/lib/modules/4.18.14-arch1-1-ARCH/build'
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (        \
echo >&2;                           \
echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";       \
echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";  \
echo >&2 ;                          \
/bin/false)
mkdir -p /home/hime/Documents/module/.tmp_versions ; rm -f /home/hime/Documents/module/.tmp_versions/*
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=/home/hime/Documents/module
(cat /dev/null; ) > /home/hime/Documents/module/modules.order
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.modpost
find /home/hime/Documents/module/.tmp_versions -name '*.mod' | xargs -r grep -h '\.ko$' | sort -u | sed 's/\.ko$/.o/' | scripts/mod/modpost -m -a -i ./Module.symvers -I /home/hime/Documents/module/Module.symvers  -o /home/hime/Documents/module/Module.symvers -S  -w  -s -T -
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/lib/modules/4.18.14-arch1-1-ARCH/build'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux: modpost does not build anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715259/linux-modpost-does-not-build-anything)

Comment: It seems that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24840679/3440745) is suited for you: the name of `obj-m` variable is wrong in your Makefile, instead of common dash (`-`) it contains "long dash".

Comment: @Tsyvarev , you are right about the dash! Thank you so much!