# Unable to insert module to kernel

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, kernel-module, insmod

This is my introduction to kernel module. I'm following [The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/lkmpg.pdf) and just wrote my first simple module.

This is my module file `hello.c`;

```
/*
*  hello.c − The simplest kernel module. 
*/
#include <linux/module.h>       /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h>       /* Needed for KERN_INFO */

int init_module(void)
{        
printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world 1.\n");        

/*          
* A non 0 return means init_module failed; module can't be loaded.          
*/        
return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void){
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye world 1.\n");
}

module_init(init_module);
module_exit(cleanup_module);
```

here is my `Makefile`

```
obj−m += hello.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

when I run `make` command, this is what I get..

> make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-45-generic/build M=/home/nailaakbar modules
>
> make[1](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/lkmpg.pdf): Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-45-generic'
>
> Building modules, stage 2.
>
> MODPOST 0 modules
>
> make[1](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/lkmpg.pdf): Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-45-generic'

[image: make result]

but now when I try to insert it in kernel by using this command;

```
sudo insmod hello.k
```

I got this error

> insmod: ERROR: could not load module hello.ko: No such file or directory

I've tried different solutions like making both functions static, or changing files location but nothing worked out.

> Currently I'm running all these commands on Desktop and I'm using dual
> boot for linux environment.

Can anyone help me out that what I'm doing wrong here??

**Possible duplicate question actually solved my issue but it was not directly my issue. I went through that question during my issue searching but couldn't get the idea. It was actually one comment on my question, that changed my view for error and then that mentioned answer resolved my issue.**

Comment: As you can see from the build log, no modules has been built (`MODPOST 0 modules`). So attempting to load a module is just a waste. BTW, the build log should be in the **textual** form, which allows to search words and phrases it, not in the form of *image*. Please, fix that issue with your question.

Comment: Updated log in textual form..

Comment: Hm, do you actually have the `hello.c` and `Makefile` **directly** under your home directory `/home/nailaakbar`? This is not an error but just for being sure: normally, the home directory has subdirectories in it.

Comment: First I was doing it in sub-directories but then to making it sure, I put both files in home directory

Comment: You have non-standard dash (`-`) in your Makefile. So you don't assign `obj-m` which has a special meaning for Linux kernel build system. That [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32673436/3440745) tells exactly about this problem. And your question seems to be a duplicate of the one the answer corresponds to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux: modpost does not build anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715259/linux-modpost-does-not-build-anything)

Comment: You actually saved me. Thank you so much.  issue was in obj-m dash.  Can you post it as Answer? I can't say it as duplicate because at first I couldn't get the idea that MODSPOT 0 modules means no module, Your comment made my focus there. So if anyone like me stuck, it can show them right way.. So please write these 2 points as answer.

Comment: Duplicate means that you have the **same problem**, possible expressed by **different description**. Duplicate doesn't mean that your question will be removed immediately. It just means that the question is already answered (in other place), so we don't need to repeat the answer. If someone else finds "could not load module" error, but doesn't note `MODPOST 0 modules` line, then he/she will find **your question**. Then, using duplicate link, he will find original problem description and the answer on it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been resolved by undisclosed means

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Why VTC as *off-topic*, if a *duplicate* CV is already casted, and the asker confirms (in the question post) that the duplicate actually solves his issue?